# Porting Node.js script to Python

Tags: python, node.js

I want to port this Node.js script to control a Sky box over into Python, https://github.com/dalhundal/sky-remote/blob/master/sky-remote.js

I've gone through and done the best that I can do, code is below;

```
import time, math, socket, struct, time
from array import array

    #sky q port 5900

    class remote:
        commands={"power": 0, "select": 1, "backup": 2, "dismiss": 2, "channelup": 6, "channeldown": 7, "interactive": 8, "sidebar": 8, "help": 9, "services": 10, "search": 10, "tvguide": 11, "home": 11, "i": 14, "text": 15,  "up": 16, "down": 17, "left": 18, "right": 19, "red": 32, "green": 33, "yellow": 34, "blue": 35, 0: 48, 1: 49, 2: 50, 3: 51, 4: 52, 5: 53, 6: 54, 7: 55, 8: 56, 9: 57, "play": 64, "pause": 65, "stop": 66, "record": 67, "fastforward": 69, "rewind": 71, "boxoffice": 240, "sky": 241}
        connectTimeout = 1000;

        def __init__(self, ip, port=49160):
            self.ip=ip
            self.port=port

        def showCommands(self):
            for command, value in self.commands.iteritems():
                print str(command)+ " : "+str(value) 

        def getCommand(self, code):
            try:
                return self.commands[code]
            except:
                print "Error: command '"+code+"' is not valid"
                return False

        def press (self, sequence):
            if isinstance(sequence, list):
                for item in sequence:
                    toSend=self.getCommand(item)
                    if toSend:
                        self.sendCommand(toSend)
                        time.sleep(0.5)

            else:
                toSend=self.getCommand(sequence)
                if toSend:
                    self.sendCommand(toSend)    

        def sendCommand(self, code):
            commandBytes = array('l', [4,1,0,0,0,0, int(math.floor(224 + (code/16))), code % 16])

            try:
                client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            except socket.error, msg:
                print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
                return

            try:
                client.connect((self.ip, self.port))
            except:
                print "Failed to connect to client"
                return

            l=12
            timeout=time.time()+self.connectTimeout

            while 1:
                data=client.recv(1024)
                data=data

                if len(data)<24:
                    client.sendall(data[0:l])
                    l=1
                else:
                    client.sendall(buffer(commandBytes))
                    commandBytes[1]=0
                    client.sendall(buffer(commandBytes))
                    client.close()
                    break

                if time.time() > timeout:
                    print "timeout error"
                    break
```

I think the issue is how I form the buffers? I'm not entirely sure as this is the first time I've dealt with buffers.
Having read through the Node.js documentation on new Buffer, it looks like it creates an array of Octets, whereas what I have is an array of ints, I may be wrong but an Octet is 8bits whilst an int is 4bits, I've tried changing the array to long and double, but this doesn't seem to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had the time to have a quick read through on how Node.js handles buffers and buffers in general and it looks like what I thought was right.

Change;

```
commandBytes = array('l', [4,1,0,0,0,0, int(math.floor(224 + (code/16))), code % 16])
```

to;

```
commandBytes = bytearray([4,1,0,0,0,0, int(math.floor(224 + (code/16))), code % 16])
```

Also, then just pass the bytearray;

```
client.sendall(commandBytes)
```

instead of;

```
client.sendall(buffer(commandBytes))
```